# Sending email to multiple recipients via express-mailer issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm creating a simple send mail function using **nodejs**. the emails are handled by the **express-mailer** module

Below is a section of my **app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mailer = require('express-mailer');
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

mailer.extend(app, {
    from: 'no-reply@example.com',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    secureConnection: true,
    port: 465,
    transportMethod: 'SMTP',
    auth: {
        user: 'mymail@gmail.com',
        pass: 'mygmailpass'
    }
});

app.mailer.send('email', {
    to: 'test75@gmail.com,test4@gmail.com,test21@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Password reset', // REQUIRED. 
    body: 'Your Password is set to xxxxx. Please log in back.,',
    otherProperty: 'Other Property'
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {

        console.log(err);

        return;
    }
    console.log('mail sent');
});
```

and this is my email template, **email.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(http-equiv = 'Content-Type', content = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8')
    title= subject
    body
      p
        =body
```

the above app works well, the emails are fired to the recipient(s). issue is when there are more than one recipient, this is an image of how the individual recipient receives the email:

[image]

notice on the above image how when the recipient receives the email, they can view all the other recipients who have also received the same email. what is causing this behavior and how can it be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Currently In your case**

Here it is actually one single email that is being sent to multiple recipients. You instead need to send a separate email to each individual recipient to achieve your goal.

**Options**

1. You will have to use a loop and send individual emails to each recipient.
2. You can use the `bcc` option to hide the email addresses.

If you put all emails in the `to` field then there is no way you can hide the email addresses from other recipients.

For example update the code as below

```
var addresses = ['test75@gmail.com','test4@gmail.com','test21@gmail.com'];

var index, len;
for (index = 0, len = addresses.length; index < len; index++) {
  var email = addresses[index]; 
  app.mailer.send('email', {
    to: email,
    subject: 'Password reset', // REQUIRED. 
    body: 'Your Password is set to xxxxx. Please log in back.,',
    otherProperty: 'Other Property'
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) {

        console.log(err);

        return;
    }
    console.log('mail sent');
  });
}
```

Comment: excellent. thankyou! went for the `bcc` option but will switch to using a loop when the demands of the app change